# Spring Boot App with Logback does not log to specified location as Systemd Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, systemd

I have a logback for profile `prod` such that it's named `logback-prod.xml` in my `resources` directory within the Spring Boot project. I have created a `systemd` service with the following configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=TopFind Search API & Service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=topfind-apps
ExecStart=/opt/jdk-13/bin/java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar /home/topfind-apps/apps/api/search-api.jar SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The logback file for `prod` profile points to location where log files should be stored and zipped after 30 days. The following is my logback file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <!-- ENVIRONMENT properties -->
    <property name="APP_NAME" value="search-api"/>
    <property name="USER_PROFILE" value="topfind-apps"/>
    <property name="LOGS" value="/home/${USER_PROFILE}/logs/${APP_NAME}"/>

    <appender name="FileRolling" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/${APP_NAME}.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/${APP_NAME}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- 30 days to keep -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] - %p - %class{36}.%M %L - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] - %p - %class{36}.%M %L - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="search-api" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FileRolling"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FileRolling"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

The following logging configuration lines exist in `application-prod.properties` within the project:

```
# Logback
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
logging.level.topfind-api=INFO
logging.pattern.file=%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n
logging.pattern.console=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
```

When I launch the `systemd` service, I can see the logs through `journalctl`, however the log files are not created. Any suggestions on where I might be going wrong?

**Note:** I do not have `default` profile `application.properties` and `logback.xml` files. Not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do is add
`logging.config=classpath:logback-prod.xml` in `application-prod.properties` file.

For some reason I was expecting it to be picked up automatically based on **profile** name given.